# Packaking application with MSIX package installer not including sqlite .db file in VFS c:\windows\system32

Tags: sqlite, msix

I was reading this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes to help me package a sqlite .db file part of my MSIX package installer, it says to create a folder called VFS and inside I have placed SystemX86 and inside that folder I placed my .db file, but when I run the program from the .msix package installer it doesnt access my .db

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this.  I was using the 32bit directory (SystemX86 VFS) but my application is 64-bit, so I used the correct name and it worked.

Comment: So in my project I must create a folder called VFS/SystemX86/file.exe and when I create the msfix and install it, in system32 will the file.exe be?